# Scan or Query operation on DynamoDB using python Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have users table, users have **user_id** field.

I need to get all the user details with given list, like ["1234","3456"].

There is no contain like queries in Boto3.

I'm using

```
response = table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('user_id').is_in(["1234","3456"]))
```

But I'm not getting the expected results.

Correct me If I missed anything.

Comment: try to use `in(["1234","3456"])` instead of `is_in`.

Comment: In Boto3 we dont have any option like "in"

Answer (score 1):

One question that you need to answer is: user_id is your DynamoDB Hash/Partition Key? If it is, then the operation that you are looking for is: BatchGetItem. You can see how it works [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_get_item).

If user_id is not your Partition/Hash Key, a first (and wrong) solution would be to scan the entire table and filter its data (a very expensive method that should be avoided at all costs). A second, more efficient solution would be to create a global index (GSI) using user_id as Hash/Partition Key and project the data to be returned in the index. You can learn more about GSI's [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html).